# How can I put a df.iloc in this function in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I try to add `df.iloc[0,2]` to the `search_box.send_keys` method it does not work and it gives me this error

code:

```
import time from selenium 
import webdriver ​ 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://www.starlink.com/');
# time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
# element = element.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'foo') 
search_box = driver.find_element_by_id('service-input')
search_box.send_keys(df.iloc[0,2])
# search_box.submit()
# time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
# driver.quit()
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-d7c71f160ef6> in <module>
      7 # element = element.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'foo')
      8 search_box = driver.find_element_by_id('service-input')
----> 9 search_box.send_keys(df.iloc[0,2])
     10 # search_box.submit()
     11 # time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py in send_keys(self, *value)
    476 
    477         self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
--> 478                       {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
    479                        'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
    480 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\utils.py in keys_to_typing(value)
    148                 typing.append(val[i])
    149         else:
--> 150             for i in range(len(val)):
    151                 typing.append(val[i])
    152     return typing

TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()
```

Comment: According to the error message it looks like it expects a `string` and you're sending it a `float`. Try to print the value of `df.iloc[0,2]` is there a float in there?

Comment: when I do df.iloc[0,2] i get 35.6897

Comment: read the above comment again :-) eventually you can try to use `str(df.iloc[0,2])` and see if that’ll make it better

Comment: what do you mean is there a float in there?

Comment: `35.6897` is what's called a `float` type. Its one of the primitive data structures in python. https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/data-structures-python

Answer (score 0):

I used `str(df.iloc[0,2])` and it worked